# Capturing composer closure in QGIS 3

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, print-composer, pyqgis-3

With QGIS 2.18, I used to capture the composer closure with PyQGIS, the class QgsComposerView and its composerViewHide signal:

```
self.obj_compo.composerView.composerViewHide.connect(self.raiseModule)
```

Now, there is the QGIS 3 answer:

> AttributeError: 'composerClass' object has no attribute 'composerView'

I guess this is because "composer related methods have been removed from the public API and Python bindings. These classes have been replaced with the new layouts engine, based on `QgsLayout`, `QgsLayoutItem`, and the other related classes."

But I can't find a signal in `QgsLayout` class or a parent to capture the composer closure. If someone has any clues...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `QgisInterface` class has the following signals which you should be able to make work for you:

[layoutDesignerClosed](https://qgis.org/api/classQgisInterface.html#ab77f99ed7774952cbce124ea5c880e35)

[layoutDesignerOpened](https://qgis.org/api/classQgisInterface.html#ad48fc0421d29316ee36fa84870ee0810)

[layoutDesignerWillBeClosed](https://qgis.org/api/classQgisInterface.html#a198591fd9e524565a512444c47c4cb79)

These signals will be emitted when *any* print layout is opened/closed etc. but the latter two also emit the `QgsLayoutDesignerInterface` object which you can catch in a slot function. So, if you only want to target a specific layout you could do something like:

```
def layoutClosed(designer):
    if designer.window().windowTitle() == 'Some layout name':
        #Do something here

iface.layoutDesignerWillBeClosed.connect(layoutClosed)
```

The above is just an example which I tested in the Python console. It seems your code is inside a plugin so you will need to modify accordingly e.g. put the signal/slot connection inside the `initGui(self)` method, and make iface and slot function instance attribute/ method etc.

To be honest, while this should work, it doesn't seem particularly elegant but I can't readily see a better solution. If someone knows a better way- I will be glad to learn it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked great. Do you know why using layoutDesignerwillBeClosed signal, and not layoutDesignerClosed ?

Comment: @V Damoy, if you look at the docs for these signals you will see that `layoutDesignerWillBeClosed` is "Emitted before a layout designer is going to be closed and deleted" & also allows you to catch the designer object so you can do something with it before it's deleted. Whereas `layoutDesignerClosed` is emitted after a layout is closed & doesn't emit the designer object. It's just a signal that a layout has been closed. So basically, if you want to be able to do something with a layout object before it's closed you need to use `layoutDesignerWillBeClosed`.